# Conditionally set CSS class

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, erb

How to convert this ERB code:

```
<div <%= 'class="highlight"' if job.done %>>
```

into Haml code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
%div{class:job.done && "highlight"}
```

*If you set an attribute to `false` or `nil`, Haml will omit the attribute altogether.*

Answer (score 17):

```
%div{:class => ('hightlight' if job.done)}
```

I believe would also do the trick, and doesn't create class= '' if job.done == false, also looks more like your initial code

Answer (score -1):

```
%div{job.done ? {:class => "highlight"} : {}}

%div{:class => job.done ? "highlight" : ""}
```

Comment: The latter actually creates `<div class=''></div>`, an empty class. This is functionally the same, but not the same output as requested by the OP.

Comment: @Phrogz Right, but in most cases it's ok. Your way is probably better, I didn't know it.